# Access 2016 VBA, UniqueTable property error 2455 and KB3115503

Tags: ms-access, vba, patch, ms-access-2016

My question is a mix of a development and an administration question, but since it affects mainly developers and refers to a development tool (Access, VBA and the Form model), I am posting it here and hope that I don't get flamed. Having said this:

I have converted an Access 2010 x64 .adp project to Access 2016 .accdb, which was not too difficult. But now, whenever I am running code which references the `UniqueTable` property of a form, I am getting the following error:

```
Run time error 2455 You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property UniqueTable.
```

This is a known issue with Access 2013 and Access 2016; see [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-access/uniquetable-property-broken-in-access-2013-hot-fix/8e92ec3b-8808-41af-92d4-0d5d72849450?page=1), for example.

Microsoft has made a fix - see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3115503/december-6-2016-update-for-access-2016-kb3115503).

And here is the problem: A few days ago, I have installed Office 2016 x64. When trying to apply the fix mentioned above, I am only getting the following message:

```
There are no product affected by this package installed on this system.
```

Of course, I have double checked that I was using the right version (x64) of the patch. I have not yet tried to install Office 2016 x86 and apply the x86 version of the patch, though.

Did anybody manage to actually install this patch against the x64 version of Office 2016? According to Jim Conrad's statement (second to last post [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-access/uniquetable-property-broken-in-access-2013-hot-fix/8e92ec3b-8808-41af-92d4-0d5d72849450?page=4)), it cures the problem, but this doesn't help if we can't install it.

Comment: You recognized the limitation  "It doesn't apply to the Office 2016 Click-to-Run editions, such as Microsoft Office 365 Home." for the fix.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is a "normal" Office, locally installed, normally activated by license key. It is not Office 365. My version is officially called *Office 2016 Professional Plus*.

Comment: So you don't know! To determine whether your Office installation is Click-to-Run or MSI-based, follow these steps:
1. Start an Office 2016 application.
2. On the File menu, select Account.
3. For Office 2016 Click-to-Run installations, an Update Options item is displayed. For MSI-based installations, the Update Options item isn't displayed.

Comment: Hmmm. This is very interesting. There *is* a button "Update Options" which opens a dropdown list when clicked. I am very surprised by that because I have got this version as an ISO file from our account at the Microsoft partner center (actually, we have a MAPS (Microsoft Action Pack Subscription)). Any idea how I could get the MSI-based installation (we don't have a volume licensing enterprise agreement)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know for Office, ask your dealer. But for`MS-Access`the runtime-version (at least access runtime 2013) is MSI-based.

Comment: This again is extremely interesting. I'll see if I can make something reasonable from it. In this moment, I don't think so because it would eventually help end users running that software, but I still could not debug it using the full version of Access 2013. By the way, using 2013 would be acceptable for me (although I was asking for 2016), because it would buy me three more years (Office 2010 is EOL next year, which forces us and our customers to upgrade for security reasons).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Your comments actually didn't solve my *problem* (because it cannot be solved), but your first comment actually exactly answers my *question*. Hence, if you make your first comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the uniquie table setting really not of any use in Access (non adp). As far as I can tell, the setting tells (told) Access to use the PK from the source data table, and as a result should not effect anything of value I can think of here.

What I would do is open up the form(s) in design mode in the ADP project, and simply blank out the setting BEFORE you import the table into the accDB. The issue is you can't get at and remove this non need setting in the accDB, but it persists when you copy from the ADP.

So, simply blank out the uniqueTable setting in the ADP and then import the tables. You could also write a loop, and do all of the forms in one shot before you import them into access (so, I guess working on a copy would make sense).

So the issue here is that the setting persists when you copy the table into the accDB, but THEN you can't get at, or change, or remove this setting since it is not exposed via code, or the property sheet.

So, the simple solution here is remove the setting in the ADP application before you import the forms into the accDB.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just removing the problem is even easier in that case since the `UniqueTable` property is always assigned dynamically during runtime by VBA code. `UniqueTable` (AFAIK) e.g. tells the form which table the data should be removed from if the form is based on a query (view) which incorporates multiple tables and a record is deleted via the form. Could you eventually elaborate a bit why this is not necessary any more in non-ADP projects? How does a multi-table-based form know which table data should be deleted from when a record is deleted from within the form?

Comment: The base table is always deleted in this case. The child table may or may not delete depending on the cascade delete settings. I was not aware you could specify the table to delete, and I would have to think that 99 out 100 cases, the base table, and not any child (left) joined in table would be the one you want to delete the record from. You mean I hit delete, and only 3 text boxes based on a child (left join) table is to now delete? (that would win awards for confusing the user).

Comment: And as far as I know, SQL server rules require you to specify the table in the delete command, so likely this was for sql server. One should REALLY avoid basing a form on multiple tables for editing, as often that query will not be up-datable. For a form that is only based on one table, you do not want to use a view, but simply set the form to the base table (linked table) in the record source setting (property sheet).

Comment: You are totally right. Deleting the records from child tables instead of the main table would be silly. But I am mistrustful regarding Access's abilities in this case. After all, `UniqueTable` is still documented even for Access 2019 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.uniquetable), and I am really not sure if a form will delete records from the *wrong* table when this property isn't set. I also agree that forms should be based on tables and not on views, but I am trying to bring complex old applications from Access 2007 and 2010 into the present ...

Comment: the property only every applied to ADP, and thus that documentation is kind of incorrect. That property is depreciated, and you can't even get at the property in VBA with non ADP projects. Since ADP was dropped for 2010, then the documentation is thus outdated. Access + ODBC tables to MySQL, SQL server, Oracle  etc. have been used for 20+ years by Access, and in that time frame I never see one post, one article, or one reference or statement that a delete command in a form screwed up. So, not a worry.

Comment: Thank you very much again. What you say makes sense, and I'll try to remove the lines of code affected and see how it behaves. However, it is then extremely worrying that MS had made a patch so that we can still use `UniqueTable` even in Access 2016, letting alone that this patch is only for MSI-based installations. Out of curiosity, can you make any sense from that?